# "Uncaught TypeError: content.getElementById is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I already tried a lot but every time i get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: content.getElementById is not a function" (Script attached)

Help would be very much appreciated :D took me hours and couldnt figure out

```js
var newcode = "";
var oldcode = "";

function update(){
 var iframe = document.getElementById('if');
 var content = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 newcode = content.getElementById("code").innerHTML;
 
 
 
 if(newcode != oldcode){
  oldcode = newcode;
  alert("lol"+newcode+"lol");
  document.head.innerHTML += "<script>"+newcode;
 }
 
}

window.setInterval(function(){
 update();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Check</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="if" src="myurl"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the page in `iframe` is from different domain (or proto, or port), you can't access it without tinkering in your browser's settings because of security restrictions.

Comment: @alx If there were cross-domain problems, he would have encountered an earlier error, not `...getElementById is not a function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` is only callable on a `document` - it isn't callable on an `HTMLElement` (not even on an `HTMLBodyElement`). IDs are supposed to be unique in a document, after all. Change to

```
var newCode = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('code').innerHTML;
```

so that `iframe.contentWindow.document` refers to the document inside the iframe.

If you want to select only a particular ID from an ancestor node without going back to the document, it's possible to do so with `querySelector` - just prefix the ID with `#`:

```
var newcode = content.querySelector("#code").innerHTML;
```

(but there's no need to navigate to the `content` in the first place, here, assuming the HTML is valid)

Comment: Thank you for your help and your quick answer, but now i get the error "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" and heres the iframes html: 
<html>
<body>
    <div id="code">
        test
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ok just tested the fiddle works great there, but is there a diffrence between srcdoc and src + url? :)

Comment: Are you sure the URL you're linking to is correct? Right click and Inspect the iframe element in your browser

Comment: That's cross-origin, so it won't work on JSFiddle - the error you get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null`. (but you said that isn't the error, so the problem must be elsewhere.) If the iframe loads, and you're trying to examine it in the same domain, it should work

Comment: could you take a look on this: https://jsfiddle.net/hed847z0/ its my whole script :/ :) or here the html on my server: https://gedstrokes123.000webhostapp.com/remote/update.html

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, it looks like the error given on that site is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null`. It looks like your `<script>` comes after the `</html>`, but it should be inside the document instead. - try putting it at the bottom of the body, eg `<script>...</script></body></html>`. The problem looks to be just selecting existing element, rather than iframe issues

Comment: "update.html:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at update (update.html:14)
    at update.html:25" now i get this error & thanks for the tip with script inside html :)

Comment: So what can I do now :( . You know what im trying is that a client checks a js script for changes and if there is a diffrence to execute the script, do you have any ideas

Comment: It should be inside the `<body>` too - after the change that was just made, it's now inside the HTML, which is good, but it should be inside the `<body>`, at the bottom, eg https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/f632a8e1fd7006120b30803d2acfd112 . Either put your script before the big `function getCookie(e) ...` script, or put it right after that script, but before the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: ok now its above the cookie script but i still get the error: "update.html:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at update (update.html:13)
    at update.html:24"

Comment: It's now running too early - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element . Like I said, you should put your script just before the end of the `<body>` (or right before the big `getCookie` script) - but if you put the script at the very beginning of the `<body>`, before the `<iframe>`, it will run before the iframe has been created, and the `iframe` variable will be `null`.

Comment: You can also wrap the whole script in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, if you want to keep it at the top of the `<body>`.

Comment: ok makes sense, i just changed it, but keep in mind that the cookie script isnt mine and it gets attached by 000webhost automaticly. Im crying ;-; ;/ i still get the error                   + a little question shouldnt the iframe be loaded on 2nd time i call the function(5 seconds later)

Comment: Yep, that looks like that did it! The iframe selection is working fine. Now the issue is a lot farther downstream, with the iframe DOM. With `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('code').innerHTML;`, you're trying to select an element with an ID of `code`, but no such element exists in the iframe. I don't see any element like that on view-source:https://gedstrokes123.000webhostapp.com/remote/update.html , are you sure that's the right `src` for the iframe?

Comment: Thanks, i messed thinks up when i was tired :)

Comment: Ok i will but first when i finish my code, maybe some more issues will come up. Thanks